# How to implement a long running process with progress in Rust, available via a Rest api?

Tags: rust

I am a beginner in Rust.

I have a long running IO-bound process that I want to spawn and monitor via a REST API. I chose [Iron](http://ironframework.io/) for that, following this [tutorial](https://github.com/brson/httptest) . Monitoring means getting its progress and its final result.

When I spawn it, I give it an id and map that id to a resource that I can GET to get the progress. I don't have to be exact with the progress; I can report the progress from 5 seconds ago.

My first attempt was to have a channel via which I send request for progress and receive the status. I got stuck where to store the receiver, as in my understanding it belongs to one thread only. I wanted to put it in the context of the request, but that won't work as there are different threads handling subsequent requests.

What would be the idiomatic way to do this in Rust?

I have a [sample project](https://github.com/aoprisan/try-rust).

**Later edit**:

Here is a self contained example which follows the sample principle as the answer, namely a map where each thread updates its progress:

```
extern crate iron;
extern crate router;
extern crate rustc_serialize;

use iron::prelude::*;
use iron::status;
use router::Router;
use rustc_serialize::json;
use std::io::Read;
use std::sync::{Mutex, Arc};

use std::thread;
use std::time::Duration;
use std::collections::HashMap;

#[derive(Debug, Clone, RustcEncodable, RustcDecodable)]
pub struct Status {
    pub progress: u64,
    pub context: String
}

#[derive(RustcEncodable, RustcDecodable)]
struct StartTask {
    id: u64
}

fn start_process(status: Arc<Mutex<HashMap<u64, Status>>>, task_id: u64) {
    let c = status.clone();
    thread::spawn(move || {
        for i in 1..100 {
            {
                let m = &mut c.lock().unwrap();
                m.insert(task_id, Status{ progress: i, context: "in progress".to_string()});
            }
            thread::sleep(Duration::from_secs(1));
        }
        let m = &mut c.lock().unwrap();
        m.insert(task_id, Status{ progress: 100, context: "done".to_string()});
    });
}

fn main() {
    let status: Arc<Mutex<HashMap<u64, Status>>> = Arc::new(Mutex::new(HashMap::new()));
    let status_clone: Arc<Mutex<HashMap<u64, Status>>> = status.clone();

    let mut router = Router::new();

    router.get("/:taskId", move |r: &mut Request| task_status(r, &status.lock().unwrap()));
    router.post("/start", move |r: &mut Request|
        start_task(r, status_clone.clone()));

    fn task_status(req: &mut Request, statuses: & HashMap<u64,Status>) -> IronResult<Response> {
        let ref task_id = req.extensions.get::<Router>().unwrap().find("taskId").unwrap_or("/").parse::<u64>().unwrap();
        let payload = json::encode(&statuses.get(&task_id)).unwrap();
        Ok(Response::with((status::Ok, payload)))
    }

    // Receive a message by POST and play it back.
    fn start_task(request: &mut Request, statuses: Arc<Mutex<HashMap<u64, Status>>>) -> IronResult<Response> {
        let mut payload = String::new();
        request.body.read_to_string(&mut payload).unwrap();
        let task_start_request: StartTask = json::decode(&payload).unwrap();
        start_process(statuses, task_start_request.id);
        Ok(Response::with((status::Ok, json::encode(&task_start_request).unwrap())))
    }

    Iron::new(router).http("localhost:3000").unwrap();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One possibility is to use a global `HashMap` that associate each worker id with the progress (and result). Here is simple example (without the rest stuff)

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate lazy_static;

use std::sync::Mutex;
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::thread;
use std::time::Duration;

lazy_static! {
    static ref PROGRESS: Mutex<HashMap<usize, usize>> = Mutex::new(HashMap::new());
}

fn set_progress(id: usize, progress: usize) {
    // insert replaces the old value if there was one.
    PROGRESS.lock().unwrap().insert(id, progress);
}

fn get_progress(id: usize) -> Option<usize> {
    PROGRESS.lock().unwrap().get(&id).cloned()
}

fn work(id: usize) {
    println!("Creating {}", id);
    set_progress(id, 0);
    for i in 0..100 {
        set_progress(id, i + 1);
        // simulates work
        thread::sleep(Duration::new(0, 50_000_000));
    }
}

fn monitor(id: usize) {
    loop {
        if let Some(p) = get_progress(id) {
            if p == 100 {
                println!("Done {}", id);
                // to avoid leaks, remove id from PROGRESS.
                // maybe save that the task ends in a data base.
                return
            } else {
                println!("Progress {}: {}", id, p);
            }
        }
        thread::sleep(Duration::new(1, 0));
    }
}

fn main() {
    let w = thread::spawn(|| work(1));
    let m = thread::spawn(|| monitor(1));
    w.join().unwrap();
    m.join().unwrap();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That is what I ended up doing as you can see in my updated question. What I had initially in mind was something similar to actors. I did accomplished something similar in Scala using actors, where starting a long running process meant spawning an actor (actually 2, one to do the work, the other to hold the progress) that I queried on subsequent progress report requests.

Answer (score 0):

You need to register one channel per request thread, because if cloning `Receiver`s were possible the responses might/will end up with the wrong thread if two request are running at the same time.

Instead of having your thread create a channel for answering requests, use a [`future`](https://crates.io/crates/future). A `future` allows you to have a handle to an object, where the object doesn't exist yet. You can change the input channel to receive a `Promise`, which you then fulfill, no output channel necessary.

Comment: I am not sure I understand how could I use a future, as I don't need one result only. The long running process has to provide its progress when requested, not only its final result.